# How do I install the kernel headers as requested by this error message?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, package-management

When I run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

I get

```
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.2.0-48-generic-pae cannot be found. Please install the linux-headers-3.2.0-48-generic-pae package.
```

and gets stuck at

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-48-generic-pae
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Install the package using your favourite package management tool. Use this link for use with software centre: [linux-headers-3.2.0-48-generic-pae [image: Install linux-headers-3.2.0-48-generic-pae]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/linux-headers-3.2.0-48-generic-pae) or use `apt-get` for example:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.2.0-48-generic-pae
```

It would be better to include the metapackage as well, so that newer kernel updates also pull in the new headers: [linux-headers-generic-pae [image: Install linux-headers-generic-pae]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/linux-headers-generic-pae)

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic-pae
```

Please note that this answer is specific to your PAE kernel. Most users will run a `i386` or `amd64` kernel probably.

Comment: I cannot install anything on the software centre as it shows applying changes but does not tell me to what. It has shown me this since yesterday.

Comment: @JimBob What is the error you're getting there? Please include this in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Go [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) (in your case 3.2.0-48) and download your respective headers or the entire new kernel files if you wish (currently 3.9.7 is the most stable). In terminal change the directory to the folder where you would be having these downloaded files(the headers, headers_all, and/or image files for your architecture) and type

`dpkg -i linux*.deb`

This should probably solve the problem.

Comment: If you don't find the kernel headers for 3.2.0-48 try the second solution that is to download a new stable kernel for your distribution and architecture.

Comment: Why would you advise to install kernel packages not backed by a repository? One would not receive any updates anymore (security wise a very bad idea). Moreover, the files you're linking to are *in* the repository already.

Comment: I'm sorry @gertvdijk I'm not getting what you are saying? Why won't one get any updates? I myself updated to linux kernel 3.10 rc3 and am still getting all the updates. In fact Even though I have updated to kernel 3.10, I still receive updates regarding latest kernels that are flagged by Ubuntu as stable. Like I recently received an kernel 3.8.* update.